# Is there a way to automatically copy a template into every new google drive folder created?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm new to google app scripts and am trying to see if there is a way to automatically create a copy of a google sheets template and google docs template into every new folder created. Currently, there is a template that is needed in every folder for new members and we are manually making a copy and moving it to each new folder. This is all occurring in a shared drive. The goal flow is:

1. Two new members joins
2. New google subfolders are manually created (001 John Smith & 002 Jane Doe) within the 'Members' folder
3. Two templates are automatically copied and moved into the '001 John Smith' and '002 Jane Doe' folders

This should apply to all new folders that are created in the 'Member' folder within the google drive.

Appreciate any and all help on this!

I found the below code but it looks like it is specific to moving a copy to one folder vs. to all new folders (based on the getFolderbyID portion).

```
//get template 
var SStemplate = "URL here";
var SStocopy = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SStemplate); 

//set destination folder
var SSdestFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("0B-hjh1DycmoweEl5ZmgxdFBRYzg");

//copy template to destination 
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(SStocopy.getId()).makeCopy(name, SSdestFolder);
```

Comment: Depending upon what you mean by automatically, it is concievably possible.

Comment: Further to @Cooper 's comment, I do understand what you are trying to do but... You have focused on one element in a process that involves many steps. For example: `copy the templates into the "001 John Smith" folder` - when did you create the "001 John Smith" folder?; how did you know what name to use?; how did you keep track of the 3 digit prefix number?; how did you trigger the process? These are some of the steps required in order for things to happen `automatically`. So, `moving a copy to one folder` is sensible because you only work with one member/folder at a time.

Comment: The folder would be created manually - a new member joins the team and I create a folder based on that member's name. Multiple members can join at one time so I might create multiple folders in one sitting. The goal is that the script operates like an if then operation. If a new folder is created, then the two templates are duplicated and moved into the new folder. None of the rest of the steps will be automated for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering a script to run on folder creation is more complex and tricky (for me anyway).

How about a solution that eliminates manual folder creation in favor of just having a sheet (eg "MemberList") that's auto-populated with a list of folder names, and a separate folder (eg "Template") that contains all files you want copied to each member's subfolder?

In this scenario, all you do is run an "Add Member" script that prompts you for the new member's name, and the script then automatically creates a new subfolder inside your parent "Members" folder using your prefix convention (001 John Doe) and copies over all files from the "Template" folder.

That way if in future you need more than 2 files copied to the subfolder, you just add template files to the "Template" folder and they'll get copied.

I created a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UhWGlEFfsz4Dsox8DLcqvMG-w5Zt6IcXOVju3sR0EDA/edit?usp=sharing) with instructions here. You can copy it and test by selecting "Add Member" from the custom Admin menu. First swap in your folder IDs in the script (see below). You'll just need to ensure you have a separate folder with your 2 template files.

```
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Admin')
    .addItem('Add Member','createMember')
    .addToUi();
}

// ID of template folder which contains all files to copy for each member
const FOLDER_TEMPLATE_ID = 'ENTER_YOUR_FOLDER_ID'
// ID of parent folder where you want to add subfolders for each member
const FOLDER_MEMBERS_ID = 'ENTER_YOUR_FOLDER_ID'

function createMember() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var promptName = ui.prompt("Enter new member's name");
  var memberName = promptName.getResponseText();

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("FolderList");
  var row = sh.getLastRow()+1;
    if (row < 10) {
      var prefix = "00";
  } else if (row < 100){
      var prefix = "0";
  } else {
      var prefix = "";
  }
  var folderName = prefix + row + " " + memberName;
  
  sh.getRange(row,1).setValue(folderName);
    var newFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_MEMBERS_ID).createFolder(folderName).getId();
    var fromFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_TEMPLATE_ID);
    var toFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(newFolder);
  copy(fromFolder, toFolder);
}

function copy(fromFolder, toFolder) {
  var files = fromFolder.getFiles()
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var filename = file.getName();
    file.makeCopy(filename,toFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you!! When I add new templates to the Folder Template, is there a way to have the script include those new templates when copying over as well? Right now, I've added a new template (now there are 3 templates to copy over) but the script is only pulling the prior 2 templates over. Thanks again!

Comment: ^ to clarify, Goal is for the script to pull over the latest from the template folder that way even if templates change, the latest is always pulled in.

Comment: Glad it worked! Not sure why the new file isn't getting copied over, would need to have a look at the data and the console log. Are you able to share the sheet?

Comment: I just tested adding a 3rd file in the Template folder with my sample and it worked. Did you double-check that the new template you added is indeed in the same Drive folder as the other two, and not for example in the /Members root folder? If you post a screenshot of your script and your Drive folder structure I'm happy to try and help debug.

Comment: Just re-ran it and it is now pulling new files added to the template folder! It looks like if I add a subfolder within the templates folder it won't include that in the copy, only files but that shouldn't be an issue. Thank you!